# WPF - Command and property binding not working for second DataGrid in another Tab

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `TabControl` with two tabs.
Each tab has a `DataGrid`.

Each `DataGrid` has its `ItemsSource` bound to a different collection (items are of the same type).
This binding works well for both grids, no problems here. Their rows show correct data.

Now, I created custom headers for the grids, and in the headers I put some buttons to make a special sorting behavior.

And although everything appears to be correct, only the first `DataGrid` binds the buttons correctly.

**VERY WEIRD BEHAVIOR:** If **during debugging** I simply change the second grid bindings and unchange them, they start to bind correctly!!!

So, the view model properties are working correctly, the binding will work correctly only when I change them in debug mode, but not at program start (which doesn't make much sense to me)

Here is the full code:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="2">

    <TabControl.Resources>
        <!--this makes the foreground black if true and gray if false, it works well -->
        <local:EnabledToBrushConverter x:Key="EnabledToBrushConverter"/> 
        
        <!--just a style for buttons, works well -->
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 0 0"/>
        </Style>
        
    </TabControl.Resources>

    
    <!-- Tab 1 with grid 1 -->
    <TabItem Header="Big Item Structure">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BigItemsCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBigItem}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleCLick" Command="{Binding InspectBigItemCommand}"/>
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding ItemType}" IsReadOnly="True"/>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


                            <!-- this is the button with bindings that work for grid 1 (every column ok)-->
                            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SortBigItemsByNameCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Content="▲" 
                                    Foreground="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsBigItemsSortByName, Converter={StaticResource EnabledToBrushConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>



                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyOneString}" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Property 1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SortBigItemsByPropertyOneCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Content="▼" 
                                    Foreground="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsBigItemsSortByPropertyOne, Converter={StaticResource EnabledToBrushConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyTwoString}" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Property on disk" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SortBigItemsByPropertyTwoCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Content="▼" 
                                    Foreground="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsBigItemsSortByPropertyTwo, Converter={StaticResource EnabledToBrushConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
    

    <!-- Tab 2 with grid 2 -->
    <TabItem Header="All Small Items" IsSelected="{Binding IsSmallItemsViewActive, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SmallItemsCollection}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Small Item name" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


                            <!-- this is the button whose bindings don't work (for all columns) -->
                            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SortSmallItemsByNameCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Content="▲" 
                                    Foreground="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsSmallItemsSortByName, Converter={StaticResource EnabledToBrushConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>



                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyOneString}" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Logical Property" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SortSmallItemsByPropertyOneCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Content="▼" 
                                    Foreground="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsSmallItemsSortByPropertyOne, Converter={StaticResource EnabledToBrushConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyTwoString}" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Property on disk" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SortSmallItemsByPropertyTwoCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Content="▼" 
                                    Foreground="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsSmallItemsSortByPropertyTwo, Converter={StaticResource EnabledToBrushConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: What do your viewmodels look like?  I bet if you bound itemssource of your tabcontrol to a list and those collections and commands were in each of two items then this would work. You might want to try that if it's not too much of a refactor for you.

Comment: @Andy, do you really mean `TabControl`? My tab control doesn't have bindings, only the grids have bindings. Are you suggesting that I start to bind the `TabControl`? How would the `DataGrid` bindings be then?

Comment: Bind tabcontrol itemssource.  I think the most likely cause is not finding the icommand in the datagrid datacontext because of something to do with switching the chosen tabitem.  You change stuff and it looks again for it's datacontext.  My theory is if command data and everything were in the one viewmodel the tab item gets as datacontext then it must find everything if it finds anything.

Comment: I'd probably have a usercontrol for each tabitem and just datatype datatemplate template that out from a viewmodel. So the tabcontrol itemssource would be a List of object. Two different types of viewmodel for the two tabs.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.... I'll try something like that. Check if the TabControl is the cause, then try to make that "context cascade" with a list of tab view models.

Comment: By using data templating you also force a new chunk of UI to be templated out as you switch tabs. With hard coded controls I think it'd be the same controls all the time. I'm not sure. Don't work that way.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Turned out that using a `DataTemplate` for the header does the trick. Still hardcoding the grids though, because of slight differences between the two and the amount of refactoring that would be necessary.

Comment: Interesting. So that's the same principle of templating. But only the problematic piece of UI.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the `TabControl` disrupts something and the second tab doesn't get to the right context when using `Header`.

But using a `HeaderTemplate` with a `DataTemplate` solves the problem instead:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SortBigItemsByNameCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Content="▲" 
                    Foreground="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsBigItemsSortByName, Converter={StaticResource EnabledToBrushConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```